# Agregar un item a mi CustomAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Bueno quisiera saber con mi código como insertar items, ya que no quiero que nada aparezca por defecto, entonces cuando le de click con un FloatingActionButton pueda agregar un nuevo item dentro, pero no se como lograrlo, ayuda porfavor...

Clase java:

```
public class AgendaFragProfes extends Fragment {

    String nombres_ejm [] = {"aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"};
    String subnombres_ejm [] = {"veamos este subtitulo", "Enserio estre es otro profe", "Y otro más"};
    int[] image_ejm = {R.drawable.ic_account_box_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_run_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_warning_null_img};

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view_main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agen_frag_profes, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton_add = view_main.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton_agenda_profesores);

        ListView listView_agenda_profe = view_main.findViewById(R.id.listview_agenda_profesores);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        listView_agenda_profe.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        floatingActionButton_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });

        return view_main;
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return image_ejm.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_agen_profe_row, null);

            ImageView imageView_2 = view.findViewById(R.id.listview_agenda_profesores_row_img);
            TextView textView2_title = view.findViewById(R.id.listview_agenda_profesores_row_title);
            TextView textView2_sub = view.findViewById(R.id.listview_agenda_profesores_row_sub);

            imageView_2.setImageResource(image_ejm[i]);
            textView2_title.setText(nombres_ejm[i]);
            textView2_sub.setText(subnombres_ejm[i]);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

El diseño del istview_agen_profe_row este es el item que se agrega en el adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listview_agenda_profesores_row_img"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_healing_black_24dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listview_agenda_profesores_row_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Titulo"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listview_agenda_profesores_row_sub"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="algo debajo"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Bueno eh estado biendo y solo veo que agregan con un arrayadapter, pero solo es si contiene un solo dato, pero el mio tiene 3, y nose como insertar, Talves crear una var de un ítem?

Comment: Para que funcione debes asignarle el listado que quieres que se muestre en el adapter.

Comment: Tienes ejemplos de esto a miles en Internet. Tienes que hacer que la clase CustomAdapter sea responsable de guarda y pintar los datos. Y si implementas funciones para setear nuevos datos en el Adapter, una vez seteados, ejecutas la función notifyDataSetChanged para informar del cambio y que repinte todos, llamando uno a uno a getView.

Comment: Vale, intentare por lo que te entendi, esque primera ves que estoy usando un listview